# Sightseeing in Malmö with reduced mobility?

Tags: sightseeing, accessibility, malmo

What options are there for sightseeing tours for travelers with reduced mobility/elderly travelers in Malmö? I’m on a short trip with family including an elderly relative who can’t walk for longer stretches and hoped to show her the city with a hop-on/hop-off bus or sightseeing boat, but it looks like there only are tours in the weekend (while we’ll be there during the week). She normally doesn’t use a wheelchair (she uses crutches or a walker), but we  considered renting one for her and doing a shorter walking tour; however, I could only find wheelchair rental options in Copenhagen, and transporting one would be tricky.

I’ve probably missed some obvious things, but… what options are there?

Comment: if you were coming from Copenhagen anyway, [the trains across the sound are accessible for wheelchair users](https://www.oresundstag.se/en/travel-information/accessibility/), but it would be quite a trek just to go to Copenhagen to rent one for a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malmö isn't a big tourist city. Most tourists take weather and school holidays into account and visit during summer. During summer sightseeing boats depart every hour and there is a bus tour as well.

Outside of summer there is less tourism. It is still possible to rent a smaller boat and pilot it yourself, but I'm not sure if she is mobile enough to board it.

For wheelchair rental I only find one company just outside Malmö, they might deliver too if it fits them, otherwise there is bus stop close by. https://keepon.se/sida/uthyrning

Comment: We ended up using a boat - I’ll write up the specifics separately in case others want to try that, but your answer is the more generalizable one, so that’s the one I’ll accept

Answer (score 3):

We ended up renting a boat from BookaBoat, as that seemed easier to board than the GoBoat ones. It worked, and we ended up seeing a lot of the things we wanted to see from the water.  I don’t know if I could unreservedly recommend this e.g. for solo travelers with limited mobility though - there is a set of stairs down to where the boats are moored, and while it was possible for my relative to get on and off the boat with assistance, it would have been a lot more difficult unassisted.